# I can't deploy my Apple test application to device

Tags: ios, xcode

I have created a simple apple iphone application by xcode 4.2 and my i am registered ios developer. i got a error like.The selected team does not have a program membership that is eligible for this feature.

If you need assistance, please contact Apple Developer Program Support" but i have visited the apple support team but not getting any idea so anyone tell the solution for this error.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally register as a Mac OS developer or a Safari developer? Also, make sure you've agreed to all the ToS information on the portal site. Sometimes if you have pending terms to agree to, Xcode will give you strange errors. Finally, Xcode 4.3.3 is the current version of Xcode, you should update to that for development.

Comment: did you create a provisioning profile for your app?  did you create it under your own individual developer membership (which you paid the $99 for) or did you do it under a team membership?

Comment: you have to registered as paid user, means pay $99 for apple account creation for development purpose.

Comment: actually i am from ios developer university program category.

Comment: no i didnt add device id to provisioning profile.